# Бот зацикливается и спамит разными сообщениями discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я новичок в python и не особо понимаю. При запуске бота и пинга его он начинает спамить рандомными сообщениями. Как сделать чтобы при пинге бота он отправлял 1 случайное сообщение?
Код бота

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message): 
await message.channel.send(f"{random.choice(possible_responses)}")
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует добавить условие, которое проверяет, что сообщение не было отправлено самим ботом, иначе он будет принимать и свои сообщения и бот зациклиться.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, а как сделать чтобы когда вводишь команду хелп бот отвечал только командой а не ещё случайным сообщением вдобавок?

Comment: ну так проверяете сообщение, типа message == "!help"

Comment: @qur0n все заработало?

Comment: я полностью переписал код, и все заработало, также сменил пайтон на форк пайтона